# Plotly and GeoPandas - Can Plotly plot polygon geometry?

Tags: python, plotly

Can Plotly plot Polygon geometry - akin to what would be found in a GeoPandas dataframe?

Comment: I believe so. I used a GeoJSON file for [plotting COVID data](https://www.kaggle.com/jacobkrucinski/coronavirus-covid-19-data-extrapolation) on the US County level (which involved loading in the geometries for the county lines). Also [here](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/) is the Plotly documentation.